# How to stop inheriting certain property of parent object in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I want stop inheriting a certain property from the parent object. How can I achieve that through inheritance in Javascript?

Here's an example:

```
var fun1 = function () {
    this.name = "xxx";
    this.privatenumber = 98765432100;
}
fun1.prototype.f = "yyy";
var obj1 = new fun1();
var fun2 = function () {}
fun2.prototype = Object.create(obj1);
var obj2 = new fun2();
```

In this example I don't want to inherit the `privatenumber` property to child.

Comment: You should edit this to make the formatting easier to read.

Comment: you can make that property as private

Answer (score 1):

Don't use instances in the prototype chain, inherit directly from the prototype.

If the instance with the inheritance should be constructed by the other constructor too, tell it so

```
function Fun1() {
    this.name = "xxx";
    this.privatenumber = 98765432100;
}
Fun1.prototype.f = "yyy";

function Fun2() {
    // if instances of Fun2 should be constructed by Fun1 then
    Fun1.call(this);
    // and if you still don't want `privatenumber` which is now an own property, delete it
    delete this.privatenumber;
}
Fun2.prototype = Object.create(Fun1.prototype);
```

Now look at what we have;

```
var foo = new Fun2(); // Fun2 own `{name: "xxx"}`, inherting `{f: "yyy"}`
'privatenumber' in foo; // false
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is overriding it with `undefined`:

```js
fun2.prototype = Object.create(obj1);
fun2.prototype.privatenumber = undefined;
var obj2 = new fun2();
obj2.privatenumber; // undefined
```

Note that `"privatenumber" in obj2` will still return `true`.

Comment: Notice that `.privatenumber` is not a prototype, but rather an instance property. Of course, the class isn't setup properly either.